# I'm trying to convert unconjugated forms of verbs to plural or singular depending on ending characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, replace

My code goes like this:

```
    def sing_plur(v):
        if v[-2:] in ['sh', 'ch']:
            print(v.replace(v[-2], 'es'))
        elif v[-1:] in ['o', 's', 'x', 'z']:
            print(v.replace(v[-1:], 'es'))
        elif v[-1] is 'y':
            print(v.replace(v[-1:], 'ies'))
        else:
            print(v + 's')
```

When ran with this:

```
 sing_plur('try')
 sing_plur('brush')
 sing_plur('run')
 sing_plur('fix')
```

I get this:

```
tries
bruesh
runs
fies
```

What's my problem?

Comment: one error v[-2:] -  v[-2]

Comment: That's helpful but my real problem was me replacing for some reason not just concatenating the verbs in the 3rd and 7th lines...sorry for the waste of time

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you *replace* the last character instead of *adding* to the word (for all except for y endings and normal verbs). By saying `v + es`, you add to `v` instead of replacing the last character, thus solving your problem